# Why is the "ph" pronounced like a "v" in "Stephen"? Is this the only word like that?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, proper-nouns

While I know how *my* name is pronounced, I've run into many non-native english speakers who have stumbled over this unique exception to English.  Even in the female name, "Stephanie", the *ph* is pronounced as *f*.

What is the etymology of "Stephen" and is there any other instance of *ph* being pronounced as *v* in either American or British English?

Comment: The spelling "Steven" also exists, so perhaps this question is also the same as: “'v' written as 'ph'.”

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, technically I believe the name comes from the greek *Stephanos*, so the soft *f* sound is the original pronunciation.

Comment: It doesn't include a "ph", but Siobhan is pronounced "sha-VON".

Comment: @Dour: Yep. Confused the hell out of me the first time I saw it written down.

Comment: Siobhán is an Irish name, and should be pronounced shi-vawn. It rhymes with *pawn*, not with *on*. English people always get this wrong. (On the BBC Radio 4 soap opera, *The Archers*, the only people who pronounced Siobhán's name correctly were her husband and the man she was having an affair with. This always amused me.) Pronouncing *bh* as *v* is standard in Irish.

Comment: @TRiG *pawn* and *on* rhyme for me...

Comment: @Dour: Unusual, but there's some phonetic logic to it.  If "b" is a voiced "p", then "bh" should be a voiced "ph".

Comment: @nohat. I find that hard to imagine. I think I'd need to hear a recording. To my ear, *pawn* has the same vowel as *law* or *awe*. *On* is a much shorter sound.

Comment: @TRiG, as an american, 'on' sounds very much like 'awn'...

Comment: I'm American, and I've never head "on" and "awn" pronounced the same way. "On" is a short vowel and "awn" is dragged out much longer.

Comment: @Nicole "[on](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on?s=t)" is given two IPA spellings: `/ɒn, ɔn/`.  Pawn `/pɔn/` law `/lɔ/` and awe `/ɔ/` follow the second pronunciation.  You can hear the ever-so-slight difference [here](http://web.mit.edu/6.mitx/www/24.900%20IPA/IPAapp.html#tab3)

Comment: @nohat et al, congratulations, you have run into the cot/caught merger! This is increasingly common in parts of the US (I am someone who has the two merged, though I can tell the two apart and can pronounce them separately if I try to).

Comment: @KevinWells yes, I know [all about it](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/11426/39). My comment above was just meant to indicate that saying "it rhymes with *pawn*, not with *on*" is basically a meaningless statement to someone with that merger.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The source of *Stephen* is the Greek name Stephanos. This name was borrowed into English long enough ago that the intervocalic [f] sound was voiced to become [v]. This is a regular sound change that was also responsible for some other f~v alternations in English, such as *loaf~loaves*. However, in the name *Stephen* the spelling "ph" remained (or has been restored) due to the influence of the Greek original. In other words, *Stephen* and *Steven* are pronounced the same way, but the former has an anachronistic spelling.

Comment: @JSBangs, the `f~v` example you mention is a rule though, isn't it?  `loaf~loaves` `leaf~leaves` `elf~elves` `dwarf~dwarves` but leaves `oaf~oafs` `surf~surfs` `staff~staffs`?  And what about `Stephanie` why has the pronunciation or spelling not been changed?

Comment: @Stephen: The `f~v` alternation was a sound change, and words that had already entered English when the sound change occurred exhibit this alternation, while words that entered more recently or which have been regularized don't. It's interesting that you mentioned *staff*, since that in fact does have an archaic plural *staves* that alternates, though it's been replaced with the regular *staffs* in most registers. I suspect that *Stephanie* doesn't illustrate this alternation because it was borrowed from French at a later date, after the sound change had occurred.

Comment: @JSBangs, oooo... so there's really no hope for it then.  `Stephen` is the only "ph/v" in English?

Comment: @Stephen, I'm not aware of another, but someone may be able to scrounge one up.

Comment: @Stephen: in the case of dwarfs vs. dwarves Tolkien forced the issue. The plural of “dwarf” used to be exclusively “dwarfs”, to the point that the copy editor corrected all occurrences of “dwarves” in the original LoTR script and had to change them back at Tolkien’s insistence. You can see the resulting changes in the [ngram viewer](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=dwarfs,dwarves&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3).

Comment: @Konrad, nice graph! Here's another one for "the dwarf/dwarves", where I added the article in order to exclude verbal uses of "dwarf". http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=the+dwarfs,+the+dwarves&year_start=1900&year_end=2010&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Comment: *Stave* is also still very much in use (especially in music and in poetry). And my dictionary says it's a back-formation from *staves*.

Comment: British pronunciation nephew is listed as nev-yoo ( http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nephew )

Comment: @KonradRudolph It is even more interesting when you look at just noun uses, as in [this ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+dwarfs%2Cthe+dwarves&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=5&share=).

Comment: A few words like <i>scarf/scarves</i> got into the language after the sound-change had run its course, and picked up the f/v alternation by analogy with older words

Comment: Isn't `of` vs `off` an example of this transition as well? I was taught to pronounce the first one similar to `ov`.

Answer (score 14):

I always found interesting that both "phial" and "vial" exist in English, having a common origin but different pronunciations. OED lists "vial" as an alteration of "phial"; the "ph" is originally Greek.

Does this count?

Comment: For "phial", Chambers gives only ['faiəl], and Webster's 3rd ['fai(ə)l] (transcribing into IPA). Neither gives any pronunciation with [v], even though Webster's 3rd lists alternative pronunciations for some other words.

Answer (score 11):

> Is there any other instance of "ph" being pronounced as "v" in either American or British English?

In British English, *nephew* [can be pronounced **nev**-yoo](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nephew).

Comment: Is it local to somewhere? Never heard that in the UK. http://www.howjsay.com/index.php?word=nephew also pronounces it with an "f", but dictionaries do list the "v" pronunciation.

Comment: @romkyns Yes, it's interesting, and I'm not certain. For what it's worth, Forvo has three pronunciations, and while the British speaker is distinctly *f* sounding, the New Zealand pronunciation sounds, to my ear, like *v*. http://www.forvo.com/word/nephew/#en

Comment: It turns out that *nephew* is the only word in the OED that has a *ph* in it but no *v*, and which is sometimes pronounced with a /v/. It gives both /ˈnɛvjuː/ and /ˈnɛfjuː/. I do not know that I have ever heard it this way.

Answer (score 4):

Stephen is of Greek origin (Stephanos). The ph is unusual in its v pronunciation. The only possibility I can think of is that it arrived in English via Spanish, where it is spelt 'Esteban'. The Spanish pronunciation of 'b' is somewhere between English 'V' and 'B'. In Hungarian it is spelt 'Istvan', so there's another possible source.

Comment: Okay, but there's no other place in English where "ph" is pronounced "v" ?  I feel sorry trying to explain this to all my non-native english speaking co-workers.

Comment: Well, most likely your non-native english speaking co-workers will have heard of Stephen King, so you can give that as an example.

Comment: @Raphael: You're back to the problem of explaining that the famous author "Stephen King", so well known to them, is pronounced "Steven", not "Stephen" as they always thought. :-)

Comment: @Stephen, just tell them the name is Greek, not English.

Answer (score 4):

Born in London, I have always pronounced nephew with a 'v' sound. Locals in Essex (England) also pronounce the village name of Bulphan as 'Bulvan' rather than 'Bulfan', even though the second syllable is derived from the word fen.

Answer (score 0):

"STEVEN" is the canon pronunciation because Old English make-shift gender phonetics are applied to the E-PH. However in common rumor, a user of the name may be required to know the two pronunciations presented by text key models in probable instances rendering it differently pronounced than that of the "V" spelling.  http://babynames.net/names/stephen

Answer (score -2):

As one bearing the name of Stephen, I have read a little etymology and it seems that many people try to answer the question by pointing to the Greek Stephanos, which is incorrect because the question is asked of English, not of Greek. Was there not a Norman King of England, Stephen, whose court spoke French?  Could there be a precedent in old Norman for the use of ph in the name? As well, the biblical saint, and first christian martyr, Saint Stephen, is ALWAYS pronounced the way King Stephen, and Stephen King, are pronounced. Stephen's Green in Dublin and almost all uses of Stephen in Ireland, follow the English standard, not the Scottish (v) usage (like Robert Louis Stevenson).  So the pattern of Stephen is historically, biblically, and descriptively pronounced as Steven and not as Stefan, although I grew up with a Polish lad, Stephan, who prounced his name as Stefan. So it all depends on your preferred national standard.  I'm sticking with King Stephen and Saint Stephen, thank you very much.

Comment: All of these were named after Saint Stephen. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_Stephen), "Stephen's name is derived from the Greek language *Stephanos*, meaning 'crown'." The historical trend goes farther than Saint Stephen, as others noted; it goes back to the Greek language.

Comment: The king's French name was Étienne or Estienne. Stephen was the Anglicized form of his name.