# What's the difference between ɔ & ɒ?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, ipa

What is the difference between ɔ and ɒ? Would bɔl and bɒl both be "ball"? (I'm talking about in standard American English.)

I saw [this similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167347/difference-between-%c9%92-and-%c9%94-in-terms-of-sound) but it hasn't had any answers for almost a decade.