what happened to the BrE ɒ vowel {got /ɡɒt/ (British English)) in American English?
it seems to have split into
ɑː  father  /ˈfɑːðə(r)/ and ɔː  saw /sɔː/
has the Cot-caught merger in American English obscured the original rules by which the split occurred?
EDIT:  this is not just a phonetics question.  It is a historical linguistics question about how American English lost (largely) the ɒ vowel and replaced it with ɑː in some words and ɔː in others. Do we know the conditioning environments that would generate ɑː or ɔː ?

Not all Americans have the cot-caught merger. But that doesn't mean you can find definite rules. For example, dog and cog rhyme in British English, but the majority of Americans without the cot-caught merger pronounce them with different vowels. The same for gone and swan, cough and doff, and cloth and goth.

@SK Sorry, I misread the question as using father and saw as examples of BrE words with /ɒ/, rather than AmE lexical sets representing the vowel qualities that correspond to BrE /ɒ/.

Look up father-bother merger.

You might like to try https://linguistics.stackexchange.com for an answer.

This was migrated from linguistics.stackexchange.com.

Likely a duplicate of: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/167347/difference-between-%C9%92-and-%C9%94-in-terms-of-sound/612488#612488

This phonological change in Northern American English is generally considered a different merger to the COT-CAUGHT merger. It is usually called the:
LOT-PALM merger
This started with the unrounding of the LOT vowel from /ɒ/ to /ɑ/, which seems to date from the early 18th century. As well as North America, this affected:

most Irish English accents
Norwich English
West Country English
West Midlands English
Caribbean English

An exception to this is the English of New England, where instead of unrounding towards /ɑ/, the LOT vowel was raised, creating a LOT-THOUGHT merger instead with the vowel /ɔ/.
North American English went a step further by losing length distinctions, such that the short vowels LOT & BOTHER /ɑ/ and long vowels PALM and FATHER /ɑː/ merge into one unrounded back vowel. This is termed the FATHER-BOTHER merger.
LOT-CLOTH split
What complicates this is that many lexemes in the LOT category actually lengthened their vowel, thus jumping ship to the THOUGHT category in the late 17th to early 18th centuries. This was especially true before voiceless fricatives and certain velar consonants. This LOT-CLOTH split affected conservative Received Pronunciation as well as General American, although in modern Received Pronunciation this has been reversed, and CLOTH is firmly within LOT.
However, they will be merged if there is a later COT-CAUGHT merger; this combined THOUGHT-CLOTH-LOT or even THOUGHT-CLOTH-LOT-PALM merger is quite the corner for accent coaching!

It should be noted that this "lot-thought" merger is now very rare in most of New England due to the spread of General American.

You'd be surprised at how many Americans have completely different vowels in FATHER /ɑ/ versus  PALM  /ɔl/, with the latter being mostly like Paul with an -m at the end of it.
