# Is there any English word in which "ph" is not pronounced as "f"?

Tags: pronunciation

A few days ago, a friend and I were discussing how every "rule" of English spelling or pronunciation has an exception, and every exception has an exception as well. Then I brought up the rule of a *ph* cluster equaling an *f* sound (as in *phonetic*, *elephant*, *morph*, etc.) as a pronunciation rule that didn't have any exceptions I could think of. Is this a true hard-and-fast rule or does it have some exceptions as well? I'm not counting abbreviations such as *pH scale*.

Comment: How about [*aphelion*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/aphelion) (one of the accepted pronunciations, anyway)? Of course, there's always *uphold* as well.

Comment: Your rule should probably mention morpheme boundaries.

Comment: Does onamatopeia(?) count? If so, "phish"!

Comment: @lpodman: I always thought "phish" was a homophone of "fish". Is it not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a pointless "list" question

Comment: You should have asked only the ones that *start* with "ph".

Comment: I wasn't asking for a list; I was just asking if there _were_ any exceptions.

Comment: This isn't a list question, it's a simple yes/no question asking for an example.

Comment: Are there any where the two letters are in the same syllable?

Comment: All those words which are pronounced with *p* and *h* separately have some vowel sounds before *p* and after *h*.

Comment: If it were true that “every ‘rule’ of English spelling or pronunciation has an exception”, it would be an exceptionless rule on English spelling itself and thus invalidate itself. Also, I am quite confident that I one find a rule without exception by making it sufficiently vague (e.g.: *a* always corresponds to a vowel), overly specific (e.g.: *rst* is always pronounced the same) or exclude something sufficiently absurd (e.g.: *t* is never pronounced like *a*).

Comment: @sumelic Yes, they are homophones.

Comment: Trivial but certainly the easiest: pH value (from chemistry) ;).

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇, Given that this is a more general question and has a much better answer, I would rather see that question closed as a dup of this one.

Comment: @dreamer Reread the last sentence of the question: "I'm not counting abbreviations such as _pH scale_."

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The exceptions come in two categories:

- Greek words that were originally pronounced with an "f" — diphtheria, diphthong, ophthalmology, phthisis — but have come to be pronounced with a "p" by no process I understand.
- Compound words — uphold, saphead, peephole — that are just a word ending in "p" run up against a word beginning with an "h".

Neither of those *really* feel like exceptions: mispronunciations that have become accepted and two words being treated as one.

Then there is *aphelion*.  Arguably, that's a compound word *and* a mistake.  By analogy with *apogee* and *apastron*, it should be *apohelion*: "apo" ("from") + "helion" ("sun").

Several people brought up "Stephen", which is often pronounced like "Steven".  Eh, I think we should play with Scrabble rules: no proper names.

Finally, there is an example that will really blow your minds: *phthalate*.  [The *ph-* is silent](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QH5PbE8wwMY).

Comment: A few dictionaries have admitted "Phad Thai", but alas, they all spell it incorrectly (by standard rules of Thai transliteration) "Pad Thai".

Comment: Why do you say *aphelion* is a mistake? It looks like a properly formed Greek word, even if the Greeks did not use it? The *-o* should be elided before a vowel, and *hêlion* begins with a vowel (the h sound is not a consonant in classical Greek).

Comment: @Cerberus -- so, shouldn't it be *apelion"?

Comment: @Malvolio: the p got aspirated before a rough-breathed vowel, turning it into the single sound "ph".

Comment: @Malvolio: As Sumelic said, the h sound disappears (in the translitteration of Greek into Latin/English) after most consonants, but not after those consonants that the Greeks felt could be aspirated: b/p/g/k(=c)/d/t/r.

Comment: @Cerberus Within Greek itself, though, that would have given _αφηλιον_, which would not give English _ap + helion_, but _afelion_; so it's a ‘mistake’ in that sense.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Well, we normally do not translitterate the letter phi as f, so it would normally be *aphelium*. F or k in translitterations from Greek is relatively modern and uncommon. I can't think of a single instance of f in a Greek word borrowed by the Romans: f was a Latin letter. The only argument I see to defend your f is that the Greek ending *-on* is kept, which is otherwise (normally) adjusted to *-um*.

Comment: Both /f/ and /p/ are [labial consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labial_consonant) (formed by one or both lips). This means that it's fairly easy for one to change into the other. There are phonetic rules that describe how but, unfortunately, I don't have a link for that.

Comment: @Cerberus I was talking about pronunciation—it would still be written the same, but if it had been a ‘real’ Greek word, it would have had an actual phi, which would have been pronounced in English as an f. The only reason the _ph_ in _aphelion_ is pronounced as [ph] instead of [f] is that it's not a natural Greek word, and whoever coined it obviously didn't know how Ancient Greek phonetics worked.

Comment: Because ph followed by th is hard to say. Phenolphthalein survives though.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Ohh you were being on topic, Jeesh. If you are talking about the pronunciation, then I agree: pronouncing it like /aphelion/ in English is weird, as opposed to /afelion/.

Comment: I say *phthalate* like *"fthalate"*.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco that was my point. *phthalate* is still /f/ while the other Greek words (*diphtheria*, etc.) in the answer are not.

Comment: Who pronounces *diphthong* or *diphtheria* with a *p*? I've never heard that and the dictionary says *f* too.  Especially *diphthong*: it's a technical word and people who use it should know how to pronounce it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Sadly, many, many people pronounce those words with [p]. _Diphthong_ is not that technical of a word—lots of people who aren't linguists know it, but don't know how to pronounce it. I'm guessing the mispronunciation comes from never hearing the word, just reading it, and then just missing one of the h’s… or something.

Comment: @OrangeDog — I say *diphtheria*, *diphthong*, *ophthalmology*, *phthisis* with *[-f-]*. Like in french. How would one say otherwise?

Comment: @Nicolas A lot of people say _diptheria, dipthong, opthalmology, thisis/tisis_. (Note that the last one is then either just [ˈθaɪsɨs] or [ˈtaɪsɨs], not *[ˈpθaɪsɨs]. I don’t think _anyone_ says it like that.)

Comment: @OrangeDog Interesting comment. Completely backwards from my own personal distribution. I pronounce all these ⟨phth⟩ words with [fθ], including _phthalate_; but _phenolphthalein_ is sufficiently tongue-twistery for me that I would probably make it either _pheno-phthalein_ or _phenol-thalein_. Something’s got to go there.

Answer (score 33):

Also :

- flophouse
- loophole
- peephole
- uphill

and [Stephen](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9772/why-is-the-ph-pronounced-like-a-v-in-stephen-is-this-the-only-word-like-t).

Comment: don't forget haphazard

Comment: I like how "loophole" exploits the loophole that the "ph" doesn't need to be part of the same syllable.

Comment: none of ph in those cases belong to the same syllable

Comment: @Brian Hitchcock: Why [Phenolphtalein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phenolphthalein)?

Comment: *Loophole* indeed

Comment: The way I learned it, the second **ph** was silent.

Comment: But I guess it's possible to pronounce "fth". Ostensively one has to, in "fifth" and "twelfth".  Although I suspect that in AmE the "f" is reduced, if not elided, in those two.

Comment: Also "hiphop"~~

Comment: @miracle173 — I think the word is *phenolpht**h**alein*.

Answer (score 27):

Shepherd -- it's technically a compound word, but a pretty old one.

Comment: is shepherd not pronounced as sheferd?

Comment: @Usman: it's pronounced as "SHEP-erd," since it means "sheep herd."

Comment: My whole life has been a lie! :P

Answer (score 25):

*diphtheria* -- and then any compound word like *uphold* or *saphead*.

Comment: Although, words like "diphtheria" and "diphthong" are commonly heard with either /p/ or /f/, so although they can be pronounced with /p/, following the rule ph = /f/ will also yield a valid pronunciation.

Comment: My first thought was, well, some people are just pronouncing "diphtheria" and "diphthong" wrong, in slavish adherence to an inapplicable "rule".  Turns out, no.  They derive from διφθέρα ("leather", from the tough membrane that can form in the throat of a diphtheria sufferer) and δίφθογγος ("two sounds").  δίφ is, and is pronounced, "dif".  [The more you know.](http://i.ytimg.com/vi/GD6qtc2_AQA/maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: Note that although modern Greek pronounces phi as /f/, classical Greek pronounced it as an aspirated /p/. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi.

Comment: Weird.  I've never heard anyone pronounce the `ph` in `diphtheria`, `diphthong`, or `ophthalmology` as a /p/.  Is it a regional thing to mispronounce those?  I've lived in the American Midwest, Northeast, and Northwest.

Comment: @dg99 -- they were all spelled with a φ (*phi*) in the original Greek, which in modern Greek is pronounced /f/, but I am informed by Keith that in ancient Greek it was an aspirated p, confusingly written in IPA as /pʰ/ (the difference between aspirated and unaspirated p is the difference between the sounds in "pill" and "spill" -- which to me is no difference at  all). Arguably, the common pronunciations of  *diphtheria*, *diphthong*, *ophthalmology* are faithful to the original, and it is all the other words (*photo*, *phono*, *sophomore*) that are being pronounced "wrong".

Comment: @Malvolio: Well, they're pronounced the way they're pronounced. Calling it "wrong" is like saying that the pronunciation of algae as /ˈældʒiː/ is "wrong". And the pronunciation with /p/ is inconsistent with Ancient Greek in any case due to the use of /θ/ rather than /tʰ/, and of course the vowels are all wrong... It seems to me exceedingly silly to call either form "faithful to the original," which is in any case of dubious value. There are no more Ancient Greeks around for us to learn pronunciation from, or to be bothered by how we pronounce English words with Greek roots.

Comment: @dg99 You've never heard anyone say "Op"thalmologist before? That's the only pronunciation I've ever heard.

Comment: I'm not a native english speaker, but o-P-thalmology seems very odd. Roman languages even spell it o-F-talmologia, same goes for di-F-teria. Funny that diphthong is spelled "di-P-tongo" in Spanish, maybe they have different origins?

Comment: @TylerH To be fair, I can't recall ever hearing `diphtheria` said aloud (maybe on some BBC/CNN news report?), and my experience with `diphthong` has been mostly in the context of choral rehearsals (where folks are more likely than most to care about proper enunciation).  `Ophthalmology` I hear a lot (problems with my eyes), but I guess mostly from people who work in an ophthalmology department.  Perhaps I just don't "get out" enough. :)

Comment: @Keith That was hardly known by the people who borrowed these words from French or coined them based on their knowledge of Ancient Greek and Latin texts. The historical evolution of the Greek pronunciation of the aspirated plosives is something we've only pieced together more recently. As far back as the 3rd or 4th centuries AD, the Greeks already pronounced them as fricatives, and phi in particular was (normally/always?) borrowed into Latin as _f_, not _p_. So while it's true that the earliest pronunciation was aspirated plosive, that's not the reason for this little English mess.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Interesting. Whilst not true for diphtheria, I wonder if there are any words in English that have a continuous usage that fossilised the old pronunciation via some circuitous route [  Probably not?]

Comment: @Keith -- Well, the spelling of *two* preserves its original pronunciation (something like "twah"), and the pronunciations of many two-related words, *twin*, *twist*, *between*, *twain*, *twiddle*, *twine*, have remained the same.

Answer (score 16):

The following words come to mind:

- "Stephen" - A masculine given name pronounced /ˈstiːvən/. e.g. Stephen Crane, the writer; Stephen of Blois, king of England.
- "Stephens City" - A small town in Virginia, USA, pronounced /ˈstiːvənz/

I might add words such as "uphold" (a junction of two words), "nephew" (which can be pronounced /'ne.viu/ in the U.K.), and ophthalmic, ophthalmology, etc, (which can be pronounced with an "f" sound too.) I don't think these would answer the OP, though.

EDIT - While I was writing my answer, the word "Stephen" was added to one of the answers.

Comment: That's interesting about _nephew_. I've never heard it pronounced with any other way than ne-(ˌ)fyü.

Comment: Perhaps it's a regional pronounciation, by I've always heard Stephen pronounced with much more of an 'f' sound than Steven with a 'v'.

Comment: @jamesqf: I've never heard Stephen pronounced with an 'f' and I'm a native English speaker who's been to most English speaking countries. Can you find us a YouTube like or something?

Comment: @hippietrail: Sorry, but I don't do YouTube, or video of any sort, really, and in fact don't even have speakers on my computers.

Comment: Yeah and I've always heard *James* pronounced as if the *m* was an *n*...

Comment: @hippietrail -- how do you pronounce "George Stephanopoulos"?  I think most the /v/ Steves are "Steven" or "Stephen", while the /f/ Steves are "Stephan" (with an `a`), but not all.

Comment: @Malvolio: The Greek names in Australia are always with /f/. The pan-European name with many spelling variants including "Stephan" are all with /f/. Stephen/Steven/Steve are all with /v/. I've never heard of Stephan becoming Steve but would consider that a nickname. I've never heard in English /steef/ as a male name but /stef/ as a female name in not rare, usually a short form of "Stephanie".

Comment: I don't know how people would expect /f/ in Stephen to be pronounced that differently than a /v/ anyway, I think it is more in the ear of the beholder than the person saying it.  Say them fast and they are identical, it is clear how people misheard and one became the other in their mind.

Answer (score 13):

Ones that haven't been mentioned:

- upholstery
- upheld
- upheaval

I took this further and ran the following fairly simple command in Linux that tries to solve this problem, I've commented each part of the command on the right in the interest of readability:

```
look . | grep ph |         # List words and filter out ones with ph.
while read word ; do       # Set variable $word to each word.
   espeak -qx "$word" |    # Print phonetic pronounciation of the word.
      grep -q f ||         # If it doesn't have an f sound in it, 
         echo "$word"      # then print the word.
 done
```

- alphol
- Alphonist
- Alphonse
- Alphonsine
- Alphonsism
- Alphonso
- alphorn
- alphos
- alphosis
- archshepherd
- creephole
- cupholder
- haphazard
- haphazardly
- haphazardness
- lamphole
- loophole
- nonupholstered
- nympholepsia
- nympholepsy
- nympholept
- nympholeptic
- overshepherd
- peephole
- sheepherder
- sheepherding
- shepherd
- shepherdage
- shepherddom
- shepherdess
- shepherdhood
- Shepherdia
- shepherdish
- shepherdism
- shepherdize
- shepherdless
- shepherdlike
- shepherdling
- shepherdly
- shepherdry
- shepherdry
- Stephen
- sulpholeate
- sulpholeic
- taphole
- Theraphosa
- theraphose
- theraphosid
- Theraphosidae
- theraphosoid
- traphole
- undershepherd
- unshepherded
- unshepherding
- unupholstered
- uphand
- uphang
- upharbor
- upharrow
- uphasp
- upheal
- upheap
- uphearted
- upheaval
- upheavalist
- upheave
- upheaven
- upheld
- uphelm
- uphelya
- upher
- uphill
- uphillward
- uphoard
- uphoist
- uphold
- upholden
- upholder
- upholster
- upholstered
- upholsterer
- upholsteress
- upholsterous
- upholstery
- upholsterydom
- upholstress
- uphung
- uphurl

Note that these results aren't perfect, its based on the phonetic information that the espeak program contains and also some slightly flawed logic that excludes words that have an 'f' in them. Like flophouse. I'd have to write a more sophisticated program to get better results.

Another interesting thing you can do is calculate is the number of ph words overall vs. the list above. There are 12,148 words in the dictionary I'm using with 'ph' in them and there are 87 words above. So only about 0.72% of ph words are not pronounced with an 'f' sound.

Comment: Cupholder... the answer to the OP's question is "yes, many."

Comment: I don't think this worked very well.  Many of these words DO have an f sound in them! Eg. Alphonse.  Also do compound words really count?

Comment: @JamesRyan Yes like I said, this isn't perfect, but it shows that there is potential there with additional work. Its also based on the phonetic information used by the espeak program, which could be incorrect.

Comment: This is a website dedicated to the English language, and not about computer language or artificial intelligence. If the OP is asking for exceptions, you shouldn't include words where *ph* IS pronounced *f*, nor every imaginable variant of shepherd. Many of those "up" compounds are either archaic, rare or non-existent e.g. *uphang*, *upharbour* and *upharrow*

Comment: @Mari-LouA O my bad I didn't realise that there weren't problems to be solved in english language such that a computer couldn't help out

Comment: Not if those results prove false, no. How would you pronounce *Alphonist*? What is *upharrow*? Oh, and here's one your computer missed out: *upheated*, if *uphearted* exists, I don't see why not *upheated*.

Comment: [Snaphaunce](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Snaphaunce) add that one to your list. It's pronounced snap-hans

Answer (score 9):

One more:
**Haphazard**: *lacking any obvious principle of organization.*

Comment: *Haphazard* was the first such word that came to my mind.

Answer (score 5):

*Phthisis* /'θaɪsɪs, 'taisɪs/ and derivative *phthisic* /'θɪzɪk,'tɪzɪk/.

But British dictionaries (apparently somewhat grudgingly) license /'(f)θaɪsɪs/, /'(f)θɪzɪk/ as well.

Comment: Another with a silent "ph" is *phthalate*.

Answer (score 1):

How about the confusing 'Phenolphthalein' where the first Ph is pronounced as an 'f' but not the second. (pronounced: Fenolthaleen). Pretty much a go to chemical in any laboratory....

Comment: As a side note, there is the irony that this is a chemical used to measure pH (acidity) in chemistry