# Is there any English word starting with "gh" and "gh" is not pronounced as /ɡ/?

Tags: pronunciation, exceptions, digraphs

*Gh* is a digraph in English (and in some other languages). In English, you can see it at the beginning, in the middle and at the end of the word.

If ⟨gh⟩ is not at the beginning of the word, it is almost always either silent  or pronounced as /f/. (silent if in the middle --> *light*, /f/ if at the end --> *tough*)

Some exceptions are:

- *lough* (and certain other Hiberno-English words) where ⟨gh⟩ is silent. [⟨gh⟩ historically represented [x] (the voiceless velar fricative) and it still does in some words.]
- *Edinburgh* - ⟨gh⟩ is occasionally pronounced [ə]

*Note:* The locals pronounce it like "Edinburrah" and all the other "burghs" (Fraserburgh, Musselburgh etc.) rhyme. But there is an exception to this exception which is Pittsburgh (well, it is in US and not Scotland but shares the same suffix "burgh"). Another good question that comes to mind is "Why doesn't Pittsburgh rhyme with Edinburgh?" and there is [a good answer in *Quora*](http://www.quora.com/Pronunciation/Why-doesnt-Pittsburgh-rhyme-with-Edinburgh) if you want to check.

When *gh* occurs at the beginning of a word in English, it is pronounced /ɡ/ as in "ghost" and it does not derive from a former /x/. One might ask where it derives from. So, I checked the etymology of *ghost* and found this explanation in *Etymonline*:

> The *gh-* spelling appeared early 15c. in Caxton, influenced by Flemish and Middle Dutch *gheest*, but was rare in English before mid-16c.

After all the information I provided, the main question is:

- Is there any English word starting with "gh" and "gh" (at the beginning) is not pronounced as /ɡ/ ?

I couldn't find any exceptions but English has a lot of surprises. There might even be a dialectal exception.

<sub>For example, I thought *ph* is always pronounced as /f/ when it is at the beginning of the word. But there are some exceptions like *phthisis, phthisic, phthalate* which I saw in [this El&U question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/237896/is-there-any-english-word-in-which-ph-is-not-pronounced-as-f).</sub>

---

<sub>Sources:</sub>

<sub>- [*Wikipedia / GH digraph*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gh_%28digraph%29)

- [*Etymonline / ghost*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=ghost&searchmode=none)

- *Phonics from A to Z: A Practical Guide* By Wiley Blevins</sub>

Comment: I checked out all 60 words in /usr/share/dict/words starting with 'gh' (many of which not defined in online dictionaries), and they all seem to be pronounced with hard /g/. Without that check, I'd guess that 'ghost' is the only native English word starting with that, all others being recent borrowings from Italian or Arabic.

Comment: I also checked a list, and found some exceptions, but they were only fake exceptions, like *GHQ*.

Comment: of possible interest if you want to see why this is so http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/johnh/papers/labphon.pdf

Comment: I think that's right. The exceptions would be initial <GH>'s transliterated from Arabic (_ghazal_) or Sanskrit (_ghat_) or some other alphabet with a uvular or aspirated consonant there. They will probly be pronounced /ɡ/ by native English speakers, but then practically anything will. There are no other reasons to put a <GH> first in a word.

Comment: @jlovegren: An explanation can be an answer too. It would be nice if you can put the relevant part of that document as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The paper I cited in the comment to the OP advances the thesis that the "same" sound can be subject to very different phonological processes depending on whether it appears in word-initial position, or foot-internally (in an unstressed syllable). So if *gh* in word-initial position and *gh* in word-internal position had the same historical source, it would be a good insight. But that assumption is false as best I can tell.

*Gh* in word-initial position was a scribal variant of *g*, pronounced /g/. It has no historical relation to the word-internal sound spelled *gh*. [Here](http://mentalfloss.com/article/53395/why-are-%E2%80%9Cghost%E2%80%9D-%E2%80%9Cghastly%E2%80%9D-and-%E2%80%9Cghoul%E2%80%9D-spelled-%E2%80%9Cgh%E2%80%9D) is a blog post about word-initial *gh* with a citation to a recommended book by David Crystal. Caxton is blamed.

*Gh* word-internally was a Middle English scribal variant for letter *ȝ* ("yogh").  *ȝ* could be pronounced /x/, /s/, or /j/. When it was pronounced /x/, Middle English scribes wrote *gh* in its place. In Old English you will see plain *h* (pronounced /x/) in the corresponding words (*night* vs. *niht*). Word-internal /x/ (spelled *gh*) was lost in some words (*dough*, *through*), and came to be pronounced /f/ in others (*tough*, *trough*).

Answer (score 1):

These aren't really "English words", but some people seem to pronounce "Gh" at the start of certain proper nouns as /dʒ/. (This variant pronunciation may be proscribed.) Both of the examples I know of involve the spelling "ghi" in particular, which does not occur at the start of any common English word.

E.g.

- > some of my friends say (jee-rar-dah-lee)

  –"[How to Pronounce "Ghirardelli" Without Sounding Like An Idiot](https://spoonuniversity.com/how-to/how-to-pronounce-ghirardelli)", Sarah Arora, October 30, 2017
- > Even though "Ghibli" is an Italian word, it is said ***jee-blee*** (or ***ji-bu-ri*** in Japanese) when referring to Studio Ghibli. That's how Miyazaki says it, so that's the official pronunciation.

  –"[Ghibli 101: Past, Present, and Future of Studio Ghibli](http://www.nausicaa.net/miyazaki/ghibli/ghibli101.html#how)", The Hayao Miyazaki Web

Answer (score 0):

There are some words, taken mostly from Hindi, where the original is pronounced almost as if the "gh" were "hg"; *ghazi, ghoul, gharry*. Of course, many English-speakers do not hear this, and so pronounce the words as if they started with a simple *g*. But that is a circular argument; if you accept that English does not have a specific *gh*-sound but does have the *gh* spellings, then of course they will be pronounced as the closest equivalent.

And I am not too keen on your first generalisation either: *borough* does not have a silent GH, or it could be spelled *borou*, which would not be the same. And what about *aghast*?

Comment: _Borough_ actually does have a silent _gh_ sound.  In fact, it has the same pronunciation as _burrow_, which is /ˈbərō/

Comment: Thanks Tim. But there isn't a generalisation. I said "almost always" and mentioned the exceptions. *Borough* has a silent *gh* though and *aghast* doesn't start with *gh*.

Comment: Aren't "ghoul" and "ghazi" from Arabic? And "gharry" looks like it comes from a Hindi word that's just pronounced with an ordinary g, *gārī*.

Comment: So *borough* has a silent *ugh*, but not a silent *gh*?